# Create stripe account on firebase auth

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, stripe-payments

I added a function  to firebase cloud functions to create stripe account when new account is being added  via firebase auth

```
exports.syncUserToStripe = functions.auth
.user()
.onCreate(async (data, context) => {
cors(data, context, async () => {
  const stripeCustomer = await stripe.customers.create({
    email: data.body.email
  });
  context.send({ customer });
});
```

});

but I get an error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'origin' of undefined
```

What's wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is triggered by an authentication event (specifically on user creation), not an HTTP request.

CORS and the `context` object are HTTP concepts, and shouldn't be used here.

Corrected code:

```js
exports.syncUserToStripe = functions.auth
.user()
.onCreate(async (user) => {
  const stripeCustomer = await stripe.customers.create({
    email: user.email
  });

  // Do something with the Stripe customer object, like
  // save to Firestore or the realtime database?
});
```

Also, you were trying to access the user's email from `data.body.email`. The Firebase user object doesn't contain a `body` key. You can get the `email` directly off the user object (`user.email`), like the code above illustrates.